# Cannot find the limit because the denominator is $0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to solve one limes equation but I cannot find the way. Can you help me and explain me the way, please. The equation is this:

$$\lim_{x\to -2} \left(x-21-12\sqrt[3]{x-6}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\cos(x+2)}}$$

I know I need to remove the zero from ${\frac{1}{1-\cos(x+2)}}$. I am trying to multiply both numerator and denominator with: $1+\cos(x+2)$ or trying other ways but I am always stuck in a loop. Can you explain me the way to solve it.

Comment: What is a limes equation?

Comment: Apply $\ln$ function.

Comment: @theage limes are just limits

Comment: Um.. $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{1-\cos(x+2)} \neq 0$

Comment: there was error in my equation. x->-2, not zero, my mistake :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define $y=x+2$ and write the expression in $y$, you have $\lim_{y \to 0} (1-\cos y)$ and can use the Taylor series to see this is $-\frac {y^2}2$  Your approach of multiplying by $1+\cos (x+2)$ should lead the same place.  The numerator goes to $2$ and the denominator is $\sin^2(x+2) \to (x+2)^2$

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace x by 0 because your function is regular and continuous. There is no problem at all.

Comment: There was error in the equation. x->-2, not zero, my mistake. Sorry

Comment: Then you need the ln function, which is defined by exp(ln a)=a.